# utf16 vs utf-16

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

Which line from below is correct? I do know all these available encodings?

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf16') as fp:
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-16') as fp:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. I did some searching and it looks like you can find all of the options available here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

so in this case, neither! It should be `utf_16`. Still, with my experience with python, I wouldn't be surprised if they sanitized the arg you provided so that it would work regardless. And from the link, it looks like they do! so `utf-16` should be a valid alias.

> Notice that spelling alternatives that only differ in case or use a hyphen instead of an underscore are also valid aliases; therefore, e.g. 'utf-8' is a valid alias for the 'utf_8' codec

Edit - that is definitely the correct link.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open which is the documentation for `open` links you to it in this sentence

> See the codecs module for the list of supported encodings.

Comment: ^, yep, exactly what I was referring to. Thanks for pulling that out.

Comment: even better in the answer :) well, if we can generalize 8 to 16 and 32 of course :)